# What is the algorithm of Pine Script security.request with higher time frame

Tags: pine-script

I am implementing pine script *Volatility Stop MTF* indicator in C#.
The indicator starts with some calculations, resulting the following two series:  `stopChartTf` and `trendUpChartTf`.
All calculation are performed on the chart time frame - `1H`.

These two series are now supplied to pine script security.request() call as follows:

```
[stopSec, trendUpSec] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, htf, [stopChartTf, trendUpChartTf])


Where: htf == 1D
```

Now I am plotting the
`stopSec` - result of the `1D` `request.security`
`stopChartTf` - The input to `request.security`, the `1H` time frame results

Since the highier time frame is 1 Day, I am expecting that `stopSec` will be the equal for all 24 1H candles matching the same date.
However, the values have offset of one candle. meaning:
Values are being changed at 23:00 each day, instead of 1 candle after ( the next day midnight == the first candle of the current starting daily time frame).
Please see the attached screen shots.

[image: Aug 26, 22:00]

[image: Aug 26, 23:00]

In the first screen shot the time Aug 26th 2023 **22:00**.
The value of the 1 day `stopSec` is **27,485.86**

In the second screen shot the time Aug 26th 2023 **23:00**.
The value of the 1 day `stopSec` is **27,409.39**

Wider look at values (not in the images):

*From*:-- Aug 25th 2023 23:00 - **27,485.86**
...
...
...
*To*:----- Aug 26th 2023 22:00 - **27,485.86**
*From*:-- Aug 26th 2023 23:00 - **27,409.39**
...
...
...
*To*:----- Aug 27th 2023 22:00 - **27,409.39**

The results of the daily calculations on the `1H` chart are series that the values swith on each day 23:00.

I would expect for example, that the value **27,409.39** will range from

From: Aug 27th 2023 00:00
To:   Aug 27th 2023 23:00

rather than (one candle to the left offset)

From: Aug 26th 2023 23:00
To:   Aug 27th 2023 22:00

What Am I missing here?